# Как указать Content Type при отправке данных серверу?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в `Ext JS` при отправке запроса серверу, указать тип посылаемых данных (`Content Type`). Т.е. примерно как в Java

```
response.setContentType("application/json; charset=Cp1251");
```

только в `JavaScript`, при помощи библиотеки `Ext JS`.
P.S. Все это при помощи `Ajax`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ExtJS сам подставляет соответствующий Content-Type при отправке JSON-запроса:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/some/url',
    jsonData: {a: 1, b: 2}
});
```

Кастомный Content-Type можно указать самому в заголовках:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/some/url',
    method: 'POST',
    params: 'some data',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    }
});
```

PS Всегда кодируйте в JSON данные только в UTF-8. Иначе рискуете получить кучу проблем в различных браузерах/платформах.

Comment: СПАСИБО Всем!!! Очень помогли!

Answer (score 3):

```
var header = Ext.Ajax.defaultHeaders = {
 'Accept': 'application/json'
};

Ext.Ajax.request({

   defaultHeaders: header 
...
});
```